# using AJAX and jQuery to populate divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, rss

Hey I'm working on an assignment for my degree in Computing Science, I have to make use of AJAX and jQuery to pull information from an rss feed .xml file.

Here is my website layout:
https://i.gyazo.com/023f1e02f5d310ae8e0250874b4056da.png

Here is part of the html for the divs shown in the layout picture above:

```
<section id="world" class="world-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>World News</h1>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="news-container">
                            <h2 id="heading1">item 1 title</h2>
                            <p>
                                item 1 description
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a class="btn" href="#">View full article</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="news-container">
                            <h2>item 2 title</h2>
                            <p>
                                item 2 description
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a class="btn" href="#">View full article</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="news-container">
                            <h2>item 3 title</h2>
                            <p>
                                item 3 description
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a class="btn" href="#">View full article</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="news-container">
                            <h2 id="heading1">item 4 title</h2>
                            <p>
                                item 4 description
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a class="btn" href="#">View full article</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="news-container">
                            <h2>item 5 title</h2>
                            <p>
                                item 5 description
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a class="btn" href="#">View full article</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="news-container">
                            <h2>item 6 title</h2>
                            <p>
                                item 6 description
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a class="btn" href="#">View full article</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This is my current code to pull the data from the .xml, although it finds all the items from the .xml, and then appends all the titles into heading1, whereas i would like to put the first item title in heading1, and the second within heading2, etc.

```
      $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "news.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      cache: false,
      success: parseXml
    });
  });

  function parseXml(myXml)
  {
    $(myXml).find("item").each(function()
    {
      $("#heading1").append("<p>" + $(this).find("title").text() + "</p>");

    });
  }
```

Now I'm sure you can see what i'm trying to accomplish, but ill explain it anyway.

I want to be able to take the items from the rss feed, and place them in their own separate divs, so each div contains its own item. My problem is that im unsure how to achieve this, i hope someone can help.

Thanks, Jason!

**UPDATE:**

Currently:
https://i.gyazo.com/2228fe9b78b5821d9f6ea137f5fac74c.png

I've got it working finally! Here is the code i used:

```
      $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "world-news.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      cache: false,
      success: parseXml
    });
  });

  function parseXml(myWorldXml)
  {
    $(myWorldXml).find("item").each(function()
    {
      $("#world-news-container-row").append("<div class='news-container'>" + "<p class='news-heading'>" + "<a href='" + $(this).find("link").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("title").text() + "</a>" + "</p>" + "<p class='news-content'>" + $(this).find("description").text() + "</p>" + "</div>");
    });
  }
```

Comment: So what's the problem? What have you done to debug it? What do your developer tools show (in the Network and Console tabs)? Why don't you have an error function in your ajax options?

Comment: At first glance I'd guess that doing a jQuery selection on `myXml` is not going to work as it's probably not in a format that jQuery will be able to parse.

Comment: I tried to explain the problem in the last few lines. Within the .xml, there are multiple items, each containing their own title, description, link, etc. I want to pull all of the items from the .xml, and to append each of the titles to different heading tags. I'm new to ajax and jquery, and i'm not quite sure how to do this, if you look at the layout of the webpage so far and the .xml, im sure you can see what i am trying to acheive. I was thinking if i could generate an array that holds each item or something, then i could append [0] to the first heading, [1] to the second heading, and so on

Comment: Tossing raw XML into jQuery won't work but it does have functions able to parse it for you. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you need to parse the XML before you can query it with jQuery. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

You'll also want to create and append the news-container elements on the fly, adding rows as needed.

```
function parseXml(myXml){
    var $parsedXml = $($.parseXML(myXml)); // jQuery object from parsed XML
    $parsedXml.find("item").each(function(index){
        // every 3rd item (including the first) create a new row
        var $row;
        if(index % 3 == 0){
            $row = $("<div class='row'></div>");
            $("#container-for-rows").append($row);
        } else {
            $row = $(".row").last();
        }

        var $newEl = $("<div class='news-container'></div>");
        $newEl.append("<p>" + $(this).find("title").text() + "</p>");
        $newEl.append("<p><a class='btn' href='#'>View Full Article</a></p>");

        $row.append($newEl);
    }
}
```

Comment: I came across that earlier, but i didn't understand it. I cant figure out how i can just load one item at a time from the .xml file

Comment: Isn't that what your `.each()` is for? Get each "item" tag from the XML, and append its "title" text to "#heading1"?

Comment: yes, but instead of doing that, i want to put the first items title in #heading1, second items title into #heading2, and so on

Comment: In that case it would be best to create and append your "news-container" elements on the fly and append them as needed as you iterate over the XML.

Comment: I tried using that code, but it isn't working. i saw that you put in #container-for-rows, which i did not have in my html, so i added it, and still isn't working, it does not append the news-containers or aything

Comment: It might not work 1-to-1 but I tried to demonstrate the general idea. Hopefully you can dissect it enough to understand and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: as soon as i use that piece of code, all of the jquery my page stops working.. EDIT: there was a missing closing bracket at the end woops! although that piece of code isn't working still, but my other jquery is working.

Comment: If you're still stuck, update your question with new info, clearly state what you're trying to accomplish and what you think is going wrong, and post a jsfiddle if possible.